# Rotate UserControl around circle

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, rotation

I have a Usercontrol that I am adding to another UserControl in which also is a Canvas with a picture in it:

```
<Canvas x:Name="ImageCanvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="{Binding ElementName=drehteller, Path=ActualHeight}" Width="{Binding ElementName=drehteller, Path=ActualWidth}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
            MaxHeight="{Binding ElementName=drehteller, Path=ActualHeight}" MaxWidth="{Binding ElementName=drehteller, Path=ActualWidth}">
            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
              <RotateTransform x:Name="rotateCanvas"/>
            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <Image x:Name="drehteller" Source="{Binding drehteller_image}" Canvas.ZIndex="1"/>
            <UserControl Content="{Binding myUserControl}"/>
        </Canvas>
```

So basically I am rotating the Canvas, as seen by the `RotateTransform`, which works perfectly fine.

But now I want the UserControl to rotate with the Canvas, but keep its Orientation. Just like a pod of a big wheel. I want it to rotate, but bottom shall stay bottom.

I have no idea how to do that except for rotating the UserControl by itself too, but if there's another way than this, I would probably prefer it.

Comment: Performing the opposite rotation on the UserControl is probably the most simple approach. Otherwise you would have to move it, e.g. by a MatrixAnimationUsingPath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performing a reverse rotation on the UserControl is probably the most simple approach:

```
 <Canvas RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" ...>
    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform x:Name="rotateCanvas"/>
    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
    ...
    <UserControl Content="{Binding myUserControl}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <UserControl.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1"/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Angle, ElementName=rotateCanvas}"/>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </UserControl.RenderTransform>
    </UserControl>
</Canvas>
```